# Can't figure out why my Codewars kata won't pass... error message not helpful

Tags: javascript

friends. Here's the kata I'm talking about...
https://www.codewars.com/kata/the-hashtag-generator/train/javascript

Here is the code I input. Every test invocation I come up with passes, but there's one error that won't let me get the points.

```
function generateHashtag (str) {
  if(str.length > 140 || str.length === 0){
return false  
  } else {
    let ht = str.split(' ').map((item) => item[0].toUpperCase() + item.slice(1)).join(" ")
return "#" + ht
  }

}
```

And here is the error I get. I understand that there must be a test I'm failing because it's not going into the .toUpperCase() method properly, but I can't allude to a case where this would happen in the instructions.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
    at str.split.map
    at Array.map
    at generateHashtag
    at Object.handleError
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext
    at Object.runInThisContext
```

I've commented on the kata about my concern, but really don't want to miss out on the points.

Would appreciate any enlightenment.

Comment: The error just tells you that item[0] has not been defined, it looks like your array is empty. Since your `if` would run the else when `str.length === 0` that might be what's happening. Could you check that string is not null before the line that is failing?

Answer (score 1):

If item[0] returns undefined the string must be empty.  Perhaps you want to do something like:

```
str.split(' ').map(item => item.length > 0 ? item[0].toUpperCase() + item.slice(1) : '')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening since the test case is an empty string (empty string meaning a string with any number of spaces, but no alphanumeric characters)

So it's passing `' '` (or something similar) to the function and your split is splitting the string into `["", ""]` which doesn't have any characters in each index.

In order to prevent this, you'll want to do something like `trimmedStr = str.trim()` or `str = str.trim()` at the start of your function to ensure that those edge cases don't slip through the cracks.